# Unable to set EventIDs using Common.Logging and NLog

Tags: event-log, nlog, common.logging

Has anyone figured out how to leverage [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) to set the EventLog ID when wrapping [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)?  I have it working beautifully under NLog, but had trouble figuring out how to do it with Common.Logging.  Note that I can also use Common.Logging with NLog as long as I don't need to set the EventLog ID, but that isn't helpful.

I saw the SO article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359912/net-logging-with-eventid-support), but was unsure of how to implement the suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be old for the original question, but I found this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412156/how-to-retain-callsite-information-when-wrapping-nlog) to work.
It describes how to correctly wrap NLog. Adding the info here as I landed here while searching for the keywords Common.Logging and event log.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Common.Logging [website](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) (near the bottom under Release Schedule), they mention upcoming support for Logging Context in the next release. I take that to mean that it is not yet supported.